# How to evaluate coroutine in pycharms interactive debugger

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, python-asyncio

When interrupting execution of python async code with PyCharm's interactive debugger (breakpoints) we can inspect the environment with PyCharm's debugging tools like "evaluate expression" or "Execute Line in Python Console".

How can we evaluate coroutines within these debugging tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update from October 2022**

Make sure you have the latest version of PyCharm, because they said they added this
[image]

Answer (score 3):

No way at the moment, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22961

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `PyCharm` `Evaluate async code` plugin, link to  plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14476-evaluate-async-code